# Dictionary deletion of values going out of index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
 k = {'a':[7,2,3],'b':[7,2,7], 'c': [8,9,10]}
```

where is each val is a list. I want to delete the ith term(depending on condition) in a val without going out of range. this is code for it

```
for i in range(len(k['a'])):
    if k['a'][i] == k['b'][i]:
        pass
    else:
        for key in k:
            del [k[key][i]]
```

This would work return a dictionary equivalent to this

```
{'a':[7,2],'b':[7,2], 'c': [8,9]}
```

However if the dictionary was this

```
k = {'a':[6,2,3],'b':[7,2,7], 'c': [8,9,10]}
```

I would get this Error

```
list index out of range
```

How I delete key vals so I don't get this error?

Comment: Are you only going to be deleting one value from each least or could their be multiple values to delete?

Comment: `k['a'] = k['b'] = [i for i, j in zip(k['a'], k['b']) if i == j]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you delete one item from each array, the size of these arrays decreases by one. Thus, the main loop becomes one iteration too long.

An illustration of the problem:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> i = 2
>>> a[i]
3
>>> len(a)
3
>>> del [a[1]]
>>> a
[1, 3]
>>> len(a)
2
>>> a[i] # used to work
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In order for the index and the loop duration to work out you need to do something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(k['a']):
     if k['a'][i] == k['b'][i]:
         i += 1
     else:
         for key in k:
             del [k[key][i]]
```